# Brexit and questions at the border

Tags: brexit

As of today, both in case of a no-deal, a yes-deal, or a delayed Brexit, will EU citizens be required upon entering the UK after 29 March 2019 to justify why they come to the UK, and provide any information at all about the person they're visiting (both in case they're staying at this person's place, or in case they're staying in a hotel) if they're coming to the UK to visit a family member or a friend?

In case of a positive answer to the above: is this information only provided orally, informally and off-the-records to the border agent, or will a record be kept?

Comment: Closing this question until Mar 29th, when things become more clear.

Answer (score 1):

After the repeal of the Immigration (European Economic Area) Regulations 2016, EU citizens will enter the UK as any other non-UK citizen under the Immigration Rules.  They will be subject to the same questions and grounds for refusal as other foreigners, and the government's recordkeeping will be the same.

There may be some exceptions for EU citizens who are participating in the "settled status" scheme, but that will not apply to people arriving after the UK withdraws from EU free movement.

Comment: Note that the repeal is unlikely to happen on March 29, even in case of no deal Brexit.

Comment: @JonathanReez actually I understand that there is in fact a plan to repeal the regulations on or shortly after the appointed hour in the event of a no-deal departure.  Additions to the immigration rules will apply to those who live in the EU, but new arrivals will fall under the "normal" rules such as Appendix V for visitors.

Comment: Given how divided the UK parliament is at this moment, I wouldn't be surprised if it took a few more months to actually repeal those regulations

Comment: @JonathanReez Given the state of disarray, there's not much that could happen that would surprise me.